# split routes in multiple files for play framework 2.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.2.x and looking into splitting my routes file (I do not think just using patterns will work for me though I could be wrong).  I have tried the following two options but neither same to have worked for me (received compilation errors):

```
1.  
##created admin.routes file
-> admin.Routes
2.  
include "admin.routes"
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is this one (there was a missing "/" in your code) :

```
->    /    admin.Routes
```

If you want, you can also apply a prefix while importing :

```
->    /admin   admin.Routes
```